# What are the pros and cons of the different movement skills?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've been using whirling blades to get around in this playthrough. While it is fast, it has limited range, has a "landing" animation after the attack leaving you vulnerable (using faster attacks support gem has helped here though) and worst of all, can't get me over ledges.

Are other movement abilities limited in similar ways or would I be better off using something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every ability has its drawbacks, and I believe this is actually called 'smart balancing'.

You can overcome it by using several movement skills. I liked using [Flicker Strike](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Flicker_Strike) together with my Whirling Blades: if I get stopped by a ledge or a rock, I flicker to a nearby monster and get on with the Whirling Blades.

If you are looking for a skill that will take you across a ledge, you need [Leap Slam](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Leap_Slam), [Lightning Warp](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Lightning_Warp) or [Flame Dash](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Flame_Dash). Leap Slam is STR-aligned (take it for your Marauder), Lightning Warp and Flame Dash are INT-aligned (go well for your Witch). Each one has its drawbacks, though: Lightning Warp has an extremely slow windup animation, Leap Slam is a melee attack that requires an axe, a staff, a sword or a mace, and Flame Dash has 3 uses and a three-second cooldown.

As a Shadow, you may be fine using Whirling Blades as a primary movement skill and Flame Dash to help you cross obstacles.

I believe all movement skills are somewhat limited in their range. Nothing will get you to the other side of the map in a split second.

Also, don't miss [Smoke Mine](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Smoke_Mine) and [Blink Arrow](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Blink_Arrow) if you play as a ranged character. Smoke Mine is particularly useful to set up before you open a strongbox.

Comment: I'm playing as a shadow currently so I haven't had it as a quest reward nor can I buy it at a vendor. When you cast it, does it have a sort of landing animation where after using it your character pauses for a second? I know how lightning warp works from the monsters in the Lunaris temple, does flame dash have a similar windup animation, or is it cast instantly like whirling blades and leap slam?

Comment: @VanBuzzKill are you asking about Flicker Strike? As a Shadow, you should be able to buy it from Nessa, so give it a try. Flicker Strike doesn't have a windup animation; there's some landing animation, but quite a short one.

Comment: Opps no, I meant leap slam. I don't like flicker strike since it's targeted.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill added drawbacks of all three into the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to go with the whirling blades / flame dash combo. It seems there no 1 skill for every occasion like I wanted which I suppose makes sense from a balance stand point.